# Backup Websites on Third Party Hosting Site

Tags: backup

What is the best way to backup websites that you host on third party hosting site? and what software to recommend?

Comment: Which OS at each end? Solutions will be dependent on that information.

Comment: Probably Linux, but that's something I dont know..

Answer (score 1):

To backup the site, just FTP in and download the data.  To backup any database, you'll need to work with the hosting provider to create a backup that you can access.  Some do this automatically, others this is a one off request.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/44936/tips-to-backup-ubuntu-server/44942#44942) asked last week.